# CPU 100% idle but still showing load average

Tags: central-processing-unit, load-average

I have a Blade Server with **CentOS 6.4**.

On idle state it shows a constant load average of more than 1. However I prepared another machine having the same hardware and CentOS version and its load average is staying around 0 when it is idle.

The output of top is as follows:

```
top - 10:23:04 up 156 days, 18:15,  1 user,  load average: 1.08, 1.35, 1.31
Tasks: 534 total,   1 running, 533 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65959040k total, 10021484k used, 55937556k free,   167092k buffers
Swap: 32767992k total,    13884k used, 32754108k free,  7084024k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20951 root      20   0 15396 1608  952 R  0.3  0.0   0:01.52 top
    1 root      20   0 19352  684  472 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.64 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:15.31 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:12.32 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:17.45 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:16.26 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:18.51 ksoftirqd/1
```

Which process is causing the system load average to be > 1 while being totally idle?

Answer (score 8):

Load average doesn't mean what you think it means. It's not about instant CPU usage, but rather how many processes are waiting to run. *Usually* that's because of lots of things wanting CPU, but not always. A common culprit is a process waiting for IO - disk or network.

Try running `ps -e v` and looking for process state flags.

```
state    The state is given by a sequence of characters, for example, "RWNA". The      first character indicates the run state of the process:
D    Marks a process in disk (or other short term, uninterruptible) wait.
I    Marks a process that is idle (sleeping for longer than about 20 seconds).  
L    Marks a process that is waiting to acquire a lock.
R    Marks a runnable process.
S    Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20 seconds.
T    Marks a stopped process.
W    Marks an idle interrupt thread.
Z    Marks a dead process (a "zombie").
```

This is from the `ps` manpage, so you an find more detail there - `R` and `D` processes are probably of particular interest.

Your top output contains:

```
Tasks: 534 total,   1 running, 533 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
```

That 1 running process is the cause of your load average. Find it, and figure out what it's up to. (Edit: As mentioned in comments - that `running` process is probably `top`. So ignore that)

Comment: While totally agree with your analysis, I am not sure it has to do with the running process shown on top. If you look carefully: it is the `top` command itself.

Comment: Thank you for helping in identifying the issue. From ps -e v, I found that updatedb is getting stuck. On running it in verbose mode I found that it is getting stuck on a mount which is no more available. So I did lazy unmount and after that updatedb command started working fine.
Now the load average is almost 0 when system is idle i.e. the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes, the running process at that time was top. ps -e v helped me in identifying the stuck process i.e. updatedb and its status was D.