# Load average 3.00 on mostly idle server

Tags: linux, load-average

I have a VPS hosting a small web app (apache, php-fpm, mysql) that's mostly idle for now as the traffic is quite low.

Surprisingly, the load average is always >= `3.00`:

```
# uptime
 02:20:00 up 69 days,  6:03,  1 user,  load average: 3,04, 3,04, 3,05
```

I've been seeing this for weeks, and ended up considering this `3.00` as my `0.00`. The CPU usage is close to 0%, the server is as fast as I would expect, and there is no other sign of server load.

But still, this stirs my curiosity. **What can cause this permanent load average?**

`top` shows an idle server:

```
top - 02:25:56 up 69 days,  6:09,  1 user,  load average: 3,07, 3,07, 3,05
Tasks: 218 total,   1 running, 216 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,0 us,  0,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 99,7 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  3878668 total,   165660 free,  1187816 used,  2525192 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4079612 total,  3810976 free,   268636 used.  2132052 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2200 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.02 kworker/0:0
26243 mysql     20   0 3297012 702988   7740 S   0,3 18,1 248:38.28 mysqld
    1 root      20   0  188692   3456   2076 S   0,0  0,1  12:30.25 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:03.11 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   1:31.56 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:01.09 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/1
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/2
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/3
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/4
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/5
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/6
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/7
```

I have read this question: [CPU 100% idle but still showing load average](https://serverfault.com/q/589078/83039) but it didn't help.

Can this be a side effect of the server being virtualized?

**Edit**: iostat output:

```
# iostat -x 1 20
Linux 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 (centos02)     07/06/2016      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           6,23    0,00    0,32    0,32    0,00   93,13

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,15    0,05    7,53     1,57    79,92    21,50     0,08   10,76   12,29   10,75   3,93   2,98
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,04     0,01     0,14     8,01     0,03  842,38    6,66  908,04   0,35   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,02    5,64     0,98    73,38    26,26     0,06   11,03   14,83   11,02   5,19   2,94
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,03    0,09     0,57     6,39   112,18     0,05  370,36   10,75  482,51   4,09   0,05

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3,03    0,00    1,52    0,00    0,00   95,45

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     1,00    0,00    9,00     0,00    64,00    14,22     0,05    5,33    0,00    5,33   5,11   4,60
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    8,00     0,00    64,00    16,00     0,05    6,12    0,00    6,12   5,75   4,60
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,50    0,00    0,50    1,01    0,00   97,99

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00   53,47     0,00   728,71    27,26     0,22    4,04    0,00    4,04   3,74  20,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00   39,60     0,00   728,71    36,80     0,22    5,45    0,00    5,45   5,05  20,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,51    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   99,49

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    6,00     0,00    16,00     5,33     0,03    4,17    0,00    4,17   4,17   2,50
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    4,00     0,00    16,00     8,00     0,03    6,25    0,00    6,25   6,25   2,50
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,50    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   99,50

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00   16,00     0,00   104,00    13,00     0,13    8,25    0,00    8,25   0,62   1,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00   15,00     0,00   104,00    13,87     0,13    8,80    0,00    8,80   0,67   1,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2,54    0,00    1,02    0,00    0,00   96,45

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00   29,00     0,00   736,00    50,76     0,28    9,69    0,00    9,69   2,28   6,60
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00   29,00     0,00   736,00    50,76     0,28    9,69    0,00    9,69   2,28   6,60
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1,01    0,00    1,01    0,50    0,00   97,49

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    3,00     0,00    12,00     8,00     0,02    6,33    0,00    6,33   6,33   1,90
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    2,00     0,00    12,00    12,00     0,02    9,50    0,00    9,50   9,50   1,90
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,50    0,00    0,50    0,00    0,00   99,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    1,00     0,00     8,00    16,00     0,01    7,00    0,00    7,00   7,00   0,70
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    1,00     0,00     8,00    16,00     0,01    7,00    0,00    7,00   7,00   0,70
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2,51    0,00    1,51    0,00    0,00   95,98

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2,02    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   97,98

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1,01    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   98,99

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     1,00    0,00   19,00     0,00   588,00    61,89     0,07    3,58    0,00    3,58   1,74   3,30
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00   20,00     0,00   588,00    58,80     0,07    3,45    0,00    3,45   1,65   3,30
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00  100,00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,00    0,00    0,50    0,00    0,00   99,50

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,50    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   99,50

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-0              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-1              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
dm-2              0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
```

**Edit**:

```
# ps -ALo stat,pid,comm | egrep '^(R|D)'

Dsl    857 prltoolsd
Dsl    857 prltoolsd
Dsl    857 prltoolsd
R+    2307 ps
```

Comment: Could we see some output from `iostat -x 1`?  Not too many lines, and it can get overwhelming on systems with many physical devices attached, so I'm interested in devices with *consistently high* `%util` entries (say, over 50).

Comment: Sure you can: http://pastebin.com/vHz42FQb As you can see, `%util` is close to `0` most of the time...

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've edited it into the question, as that helps questions stay relevant longer (pastebin output has been known to disappear).  It doesn't look IO-related, at least not local IO.  No NFS mounts?

Comment: No NFS mounts...

Comment: OK, thanks, it's not IO-blocking, then.  I'll be interested to see if someone can chase it down.

Comment: TBH this is a CentOS template created & installed by the local hosting company, and this would not be the first weirdness I've seen (odd default firewall config scripts, for example); I'm quite interested to find out the source of the load average as well!

Comment: One more question, for which I apologise: are you **sure** this is a VPS?  Not merely a containerised environment?

Comment: Do you know what virtualization is being used ( openVZ/Xen/KVM?).. Do you know how the provider allocates the CPU? (EX: do you get a full core?, or do you get some GHZ out of a full CPU core?)

Comment: Also, Do you have "sysstat" (SAR) installed? If so, can you please go and check if the load avg. stays consistent or there is a wild variability in the averages

Comment: @vijayrajah I have no idea what virtualization is being used. I *think* when I have dedicated cores, but can't guarantee it. It looks like I have `sysstat` installed, but I do not know how to use it. Can you please give me the command to get the output you need?

Comment: @MadHatter I'm not sure what you mean by containerized environment. I have root access on the machine. My hosting company calls it a VM. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I don't know how to be clearer (though I freely acknowledge that companies offering containers as *virtualisation-lite* can be **very** evasive about them not being VMs).  Having root access doesn't tell us whether you have a real virtualised environment, or a mere container.  As Vijay asks, you may have to get your provider to clarify what technology they're using.  Or try inserting a module into the kernel; the `usb_storage` module is pretty harmless, and isn't usually loaded on VMs (as they have no usb interfaces), so `modprobe usb_storage` should be fairly safe to run.

Comment: @MadHatter I've followed [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89718/30018) on [Easy way to determine virtualization technology](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89714/30018), and `dmidecode -s system-product-name` tells me that I'm running on `Parallels Virtual Platform`. So it looks like I'm on a proper VM?

Comment: Can you please share the output of  `dmidecode -s system-product-name` This will enable us to identify the virtualization types (most of them atleast!)... please read up on `sar`it is a really usefull tool. please see [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) .. I'm intrested in `-q` , `-p` & `-d` for 24 hours.

Comment: Regarding `dmidecode`, I think our messages crossed, see my comment above, it's running Parallels. Regarding `sar`, sorry I don't have (yet) 24 hours -not sure why, as it was already installed- but here's the 4 hour output anyway: http://pastebin.com/Jjqpe0A1

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is a real VM, not just a container.  Scratch that hypothesis as well.

Comment: Do you have any (3) processes in uninterruptible sleep (D) ? - they would be counting towards your loadavg.

Comment: Please can you run `ps -ALo stat,pid,comm | egrep '^(R|D)'` and paste the output into your question? This should make it pretty obvious normally where the problem is.

Comment: @Matthew Output added to the question!

Comment: Loadavg 1 min, means the number of process with state READY waiting in the RUN QUEUE in the last minute. I'd `sudo perf top` or `strace -p [PID]` to see which functions/syscalls are taking over your processors, but I'd put my two cents on the `sleep` calls someone mentioned before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the output of `ps -ALo stat,pid,comm | egrep '^(R|D)'`, it seems that you have *three* processes in uninterruptible sleep (`D` state). As Linux count processes in `D` state when calculating `loadavg`, maybe these three `prltoolsd` processes are the cause of the relatively high load average.

From a Google search, it seems that `prltoolsd` is part of the "Parallels Tools" suite, some sort of guest additions for the hosted image. As they are sleeping in kernel-level system calls (ie: uninterruptable sleep), maybe thery are listeing on a "fake" device to allow the host system to communicate with the guest system, hence the 3.0 load average value.

If you want to be *really* sure they are the cause of the problem, stop the `prltoolsd` processes and/or uninstall the tools. Anyway, I strongly suspect you can completely ignore them and the 3.0 load average...

Comment: Looks like you found the cause of the problem, congrats! I'll check with the hosting company first, but I think I'll just ignore it.

Comment: I don't think so, actually it was me: http://serverfault.com/a/782429/67675 but you gave the output which didn't have any `D`s at that moment. ;)

Comment: @poige Where should we have seen the `D`s? The load average is always the same, so I'm pretty sure it would have showed up.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, load average is a useless metric without context, particularly knowing how many CPU cores your server has.  A load average of 3 on a single-core server (somewhat busy) is very different from the same load average on one with, say, 64 cores.

That said, `mysqld` is your top process, and it's multi-threaded, meaning the one process can actually be using multiple CPU cores at once. Run `ps -efT | grep mysqld` to see how many active threads it has.  `top` will also show threads with the `-H` option. Even if mysql isn't actively getting queries, it does run some background tasks.  You may want to check its logs to see what it's doing.

Comment: Good point. There are 2 CPU cores. About `mysqld`, it's here in this `top` output, but is not always active. Very often it's not even visible in the output. I cannot see anything in the logs that would explain any such activity from MySQL.

Comment: Ok, then, let's look at the memory usage.  You have swap and it seems to be used.  Swapping is obviously going to create I/O wait, which will increase the load average, especially if you have a full stack on the same host.  If you haven't changed the kernel parameter `vm.swappiness` from the default of 60, you may want to change it to 1 (do not set it to 0 -- this disables swap): `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=1`.  If you can stop your apps temporarily, that would also be helpful in determining the instance's baseline load.  This answer may also be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130970

Comment: Swap is almost unused, and there is plenty of RAM available (2GB out of 4GB), the memory "used" is for buffer/cache, it's therefore available.

Comment: The `vmstat` output pointed to below poige's answer is suggestive that it's not swapping.  I agree it's a very short dataset, but if the box was continuously swapping you'd see it even in such a short snippet.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux a process that got stuck in I/O would also be counted as placed into run-queue. This is a <strike>bug</strike> feature. You can check/show `vmstat 1 2`'s output, to see if you have any blocked, for e. g..

Comment: Here is the `vmstat` output: http://pastebin.com/qtnAqJxB

Comment: my bad. `vmstat 1 2`, please

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/SRUs9Fyq

Comment: ok, it doesn't look like anything blocked on I/O. Next: `ps -A -o s | uniq -c | sort -n` ?

Comment: + `cat /proc/loadavg`

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/ZeDvHusv

Comment: ok, can I have ssh access there? O_o (LOL)

Comment: I'm afraid not :)

Comment: You're in danger otherwise anyways. ;-P

Answer (score 0):

i would check connections to my server 
(/var/log/secure and /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log)
a useful way to find out ip's that are making multiple connections to server

```
netstat -atun | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Also, check if the node that's holding that vm isn't under high load or is having issues with disk(s).

Comment: Your command returns less than 10 IP addresses, so I don't think this is an issue; and if many clients were connected and created some load, wouldn't that be visible in the commands others have suggested? I've opened a ticket with the hosting company, we'll see if it's an hypervisor problem.

Comment: When you don't see processes that are creating load, abusive network behaviour can be one of reasons. In that case, you wouldn't see processes with high cpu/memory usage, but you could catch abuse by looking at those logs. Also, run iptraf and look at traffic on public interface (look for udp connections)